# GET request with header to open a URL and retrieve header in Angular app

Tags: java, angular, jsp

I have an Angular app with a route say /register which can be accessible on http://xyc.com/register
I want to make a GET call to this url and pass a header in that request.

Now, I want my angular app to be able to read header from the request and store it in cookie.

I am not sure where and how to retrieve the header from the request in my Angular app? Should I ideally create an interceptor for this and do `request.headers` to get the header I want? I tried it like this:

```
export class SomeInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {    
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log("headers = " + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

Not sure if this is the right approach?

Then, I wanted to test (from browser) if the header is retrieved properly by sending a GET request to the URL and seeing if the header prints using console.log. For this I tried to use a JSP to send a GET request to this URL (along with the header) in order to test if the header is retrieved correctly in my Angular app. But I am not sure how to do it.

In my JSP code, I tried the following:

```
response.setHeader("myHeader", "test-header");
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
response.setHeader("Location", "http://xyc.com/register");
```

However, I don't see my header printed. Not sure if my approach to read the header is wrong or the way I am testing is wrong. Any help?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Cookie ideally is way for server to send data to browser to keep track of anything that server wants to remember. E.g. Authentication token or anything that can track session of user. What you are trying to do is other way round. I would have ideally set cookie as a part of response from server than actually reading at browser and setting it there. Ideally in most of the cases browser too does not need to explicitly set, as once set it becomes a part of every request that is send.